# Reproducing cutoff in xgboost.train() with XGBClassifier()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

(Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415724/reproducing-cutoff-in-xgboost-train-with-xgbclassifier)

I've gotten xgboost to generate good predictions by using xgboost.train().

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=.6)
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)

param = {'max_depth':7, 'silent':1}
bst = xgb.train(param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=2)
y_pred = bst.predict(xgtest)
y_pred = [1. if y_cont > .28  else 0. for y_cont in y_pred]
y_true = y_test
```

This approach wasn't producing good results (I am trying to maximize the f1 score) until I realized that the f1 score increases significantly when setting a threshold on the outputs. This threshold turned out to be .28. Here are some of the predictions before I set the cutoff and convert to 0s and 1s:

```
[ 0.25447303  0.25383738  0.24621713 ...,  0.24621713  0.24621713 0.24621713]
```

But now I want to tune my parameters (using GridSearchCV()), which means that I'll need to reproduce what I did in xgboost.train() above with XGBClassifier().

I realize that things might get tricky because the (default) objective function in xgboost.train() is none, and for XGBClassifier() it's 'binary:logistic'. XGBClassifier() returns the class and not the probability, which is useful in most cases but not here. I've tried predict_proba() with XGBClassifier() and then setting a cutoff, but it seemed pretty useless since the probabilities I were getting were super close to 0 and 1:

```
[[  9.99445975e-01   5.54045662e-04]
 [  9.89062011e-01   1.09380139e-02]
 [  9.95234787e-01   4.76523908e-03]
```

How can I finish the code below do the equivalent of xgboost.train() but with XGBClassifier? When I've tried XGBClassifier without a cutoff, I would get a horrible f1 score.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=.6)
rf = XGBClassifier(max_depth=7, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, silent=True, objective='binary:logistic', nthread=-1, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1, max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, seed=0, missing=None)
rf = rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: You can try to optimize for f1 score directly in XGBoostClassifier but the cutoff is going to be a cutoff related to probabilities of classes not to regression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400372/using-f-score-in-xgb

Comment: Right, I've tried this but I haven't gotten it to work. The probabilities of classes are still super close to 1 and 0; it's still different than my original implementation

Comment: Take a look at the distribution of predicted probabilities, what do you see?

Comment: [[  9.94749188e-01   5.25079062e-03]
 [  9.99202788e-01   7.97222485e-04]
 [  9.91710424e-01   8.28954764e-03]
 ..., 
 [  9.86792803e-01   1.32071702e-02]
 [  9.99156356e-01   8.43643385e-04]
 [  9.98529851e-01   1.47015741e-03]]

Comment: Basically you're predicting all 1 or 0 ? if so, you should smell something is wrong. I suggest before any tuning, go over again on what you're doing with more care.

Comment: But then how did I get good results with xgb.train()? Also, if it helps, this is for binary classification where the classes are "0" and "1"

Comment: Do not cross post or if you do add reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415724/reproducing-cutoff-in-xgboost-train-with-xgbclassifier

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted